# Why does unspent address index differ between APIs?

Tags: api, utxo, blocktrail

I've been using [Blocktrail's API](https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs/lang/nodejs#data_overview):

https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs/lang/nodejs#data_overview

to get data for the following unspent address on the testnet:

2N6qMqR9D4BTkD6fS1h6Sq3kRV2FeB1L14j.

Blocktrail's API returns the index as 4, whereas blockexplorer's:

https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/api/addr/2N6qMqR9D4BTkD6fS1h6Sq3kRV2FeB1L14j/utxo

and smartbit's APIs:

https://testnet-api.smartbit.com.au/v1/blockchain/address/2N6qMqR9D4BTkD6fS1h6Sq3kRV2FeB1L14j/unspent

both return an index of 0. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> both return an index of 0.

0 is the correct answer here.

> Am I missing something here?

Not sure.

I can't reproduce your problem. I'm querying blocktrail like this:

```
curl https://api.blocktrail.com/v1/tbtc/address/2N6qMqR9D4BTkD6fS1h6Sq3kRV2FeB1L14j/transactions?api_key=MY_APIKEY
```

and that returns all of the transactions for the address, none of which have an index of 4.

Can you post the line of code that calls their API?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this! It turns out that I was querying for address instead of transaction (js):
`blocktrailClient.address((2N6qMqR9D4BTkD6fS1h6Sq3kRV2FeB1L14j), (err, address) => {console.log(address)})`